# System Image Restore Taking Forever

Tags: windows-7, backup, windows-7-restore

I recently changed my motherboard, CPU, and power supply since my old motherboard was having some problems.

I used Paragon Adaptive Restore to make Windows bootable after changing the hardware. Afterwards, I created a system image of my C drive using the built in Windows Backup  tool because my hard drive was making weird sounds. Luckily I did because after I restarted my computer, I was unable to boot from that drive.

My question is if I try to restore my system on the same drive using the Windows Recovery Disc from the disk image I created, is it supposed to take a very long time?  The restore has been running for two hours now and the progress bar has not moved at all.

If all else fails, I could get a new hard drive but I was just wondering if this is a problem with a hard drive, or typical behavior of the Recovery System. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two questions:

1. How long should the restore take?  Well the answer is that it just depends, and depends on a lot of things, but chiefly how much data you have, and how fast your storage systems are.
2. Should I replace the hard drive?  I would say this is a categorical **YES!**  The drive failed you already.  Also, with some hard drives that have gone *bad*, their only symptom is that they are slow, so I would say this adds further evidence that you should just replace the drive.

Also, most hard drive manufactures have testing tools, and if it under warranty, you will have to run this tool to get the drive replaced.

Comment: I have around 800 gb on the image because I didn't think about moving some files beforehand. As for the speed of the drive, I have a blue Western Digital drive, so I'm guessing the normal speed for a hard drive. To test it should I boot the tool from a CD, since I can't start windows, or use something like an Ubuntu LiveCD to run it? Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm guessing that drive is a relatively new one.  That its transfer rate is 6 Gb/s (Gigabits per second) which is 768 MBps (Megabytes per second), so we'll assume 500MBps allowing for system overhead.  So that is a Gigabyte transferred every 2s, so for 800GB, then that is 1600s which would roughly be 30 minutes.  What did you back up to?  USB 2.0 has an effective transfer rate of about 35MBps or a GB every 30 seconds.  800*30=24000s or 400 minutes, so I would say that after 2 hours you should have been at least 10% restored.  How long did it take you to backup?

Comment: To test the drive, use the WD tool:  http://support.wdc.com/product/download.asp?wdc_lang=en&fid=wdsfDesktop_Blue

Comment: I saved the backup to another internal hard drive I had in the computer and that took around an hour at the most. I'm not home right now but when I get back, I'll check the status of the restore as well as use the WD diagnostic tool. Thanks

Comment: Okay, if you backed up to another internal HDD (hard drive), then 60 minutes to totally reasonable for that operation.  For the restore to take 2 hours and for nothing to have happened, that totally convinces me to replace that drive.